# Android EditText number pad keyboard with version like filter(TextWatcher)

Tags: android, android-edittext

`EditText` should accept input like "1.0.1" means multiple "."s. and keyboard should be number pad(I know `EditText`'s inputType should be `numberDecimal`).

[image]

But `numberDecimal` only accepts single dot and the filter won't work for this. How to solve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just add . to EditText android:digits xml value

Like so  :

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:digits="0123456789."
   android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
/>
```